# Cannot forward spark port on google spark operator in kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, spark-operator, google-spark-operator

I am trying to connect to a spark port 4040 for an application that runs on Spark operator in Kubernetes.

Operator version:

`helm install latest spark-operator/spark-operator --namespace spark-operator --create-namespace --set image.tag=v1beta2-1.3.2-3.1.1 --set image.repository=ghcr.io/googlecloudplatform/spark-operator`

Port forward command: `kubectl port-forward spark-minio-driver -n spark-operator 4040:4040` seems to work at first: Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:4040 -> 4040.

However, trying to access this on http://localhost:4040/ throws:

`an error occurred forwarding 4040 -> 4040: error forwarding port 4040 to pod 01246165e6a23710784b34cb0b0a06613477f593e5a7f07ca7b71a7a349f5bc6, uid : exit status 1: 2022/03/14 12:28:59 socat[94708] E connect(16, AF=2 127.0.0.1:4040, 16): Connection refused`

Any idea what might be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What's your K8s cluster environment? What is the version of K8s, do you use bare metal installation/cloud provider?

Comment: @anarxz trying it out via Ubuntu 20.04 + Docker Desktop on my laptop. Version: kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.5", GitCommit:"aea7bbadd2fc0cd689de94a54e5b7b758869d691", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-09-15T21:10:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}